# I need Primary keys of the affected rows to be returned after updating a table in MYSQL.

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I need Primary keys of the affected rows to be returned after updating a MYSQL table using my PHP Code. 
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: If you've updated existing records, then you must have identified them somehow - so your invoking (PHP) code would already know some sort of key; if it's not the PK but you want to fetch the PK, you could `SELECT ... WHERE` to obtain it.  Or when you say "updating", are you in fact inserting *new* records into the table?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. You'll just have to execute a SELECT query afterwards.

Comment: So far tried 
mysql_affected_rows();
mysql_info();

Comment: And what is your query to perform the update?

Comment: @Zuul Update table set status='E' where status='O'

Comment: @eggyal No, just changing the status field with Update statement, not inserting new records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fetch the primary keys before performing the `UPDATE`:

```
SELECT primary_key_columns FROM my_table WHERE status = 'O';
UPDATE my_table SET status = 'E' WHERE status = 'O';
```

However, if you have concurrent connections that might alter `my_table` between the two statements, it's possible that the results of the keys returned by the first `SELECT` statement will not fully match the records updated by the second `UPDATE` statement.

To prevent this, you would need to perform the operations in a transaction (but note that transactions require support from your storage engine - InnoDB is usually used for this purpose):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT primary_key_columns FROM my_table WHERE status = 'O' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE my_table SET status = 'E' WHERE status = 'O';
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing what you want is previously SELECT the primary keys with the conditions for the update BEFORE you do the update.

If your query is

Update * from "table" where Y

you would have to do the following:

Select "Primary key" from "table" where Y

Update X from "table" where Y

Hope this helps!